# git revert --no-commit without staging

Tags: git, git-revert

Usually the command `git revert` automatically creates some commits with commit log messages stating which commits were reverted.

To avoid automatic commit there's the option `-n` (or `--no-commit`).

But after this command, the reverted files are in the staged area. I can unstage them by using the command `git reset HEAD`.

Is there a direct way to revert a commit without committing and staging?

In other words: is there a direct command to revert a commit applying the changes only to the working directory, without touching the index?

Comment: What would this look like?  What does "reverting" mean if you don't have a change that reverts it?

Comment: I just want the local files with the reverted changes applied to them, with no commits and no handling of the staging area. That's what happens if you do `git revert -n <HASH> && git reset HEAD` but I'd like to do it at once.

Comment: Aha, I understand - so you want the reverted changes applied to the workdir but not staged.  Upon re-reading your question this does seem clear but my first read didn't parse that meaning correctly.

Comment: Probably it's my fault, I tried to clarify my intent in the question.

Comment: What in `git revert -n <HASH> && git reset HEAD` is not "at once"? I mean, does it really matter whether you type `&&` and another `git` command versus an imaginary long argument name to `git revert` like `git revert --neither-commit-nor-stage <HASH>`?

Comment: @sschuberth: those are two steps. Sure it doesn't hurts, but I just want to know if there's a direct way to accomplish that.

Comment: Not everything can be done in one command. Write a bash function to do this all at once if you really want to.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

There is no single command for it.  As you already noted, you can combine `git revert -n` with `git reset` to get the reversion undone in the index.

Besides that method, you can use `git apply -R` to "reverse apply" a patch, and you can turn a commit into a patch with `git show`, so:

```
$ git show <rev> | git apply -R
```

has the same effect, with one important (but subtle) difference.  Let me quote from the `git revert` documentation and add my own emphasis:

> `-n, --no-commit`
>    Usually the command automatically creates some commits with commit
>    log messages stating which commits were reverted. This flag applies
>    the changes necessary to revert the named commits to your working
>    tree and the index, but does not make the commits. In addition,
>    when this option is used, your index does not have to match the
>    HEAD commit. **The revert is done against the beginning state of your
>    index.**

In other words, `git revert -n` *operates in, and on, the index*, with a side effect of updating your work tree.  The `git apply` command operates (by default anyway) on the work-tree only, and in fact can be used outside a git repository.

Comment: I got _error: unrecognized input_ . Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @RobertPankowecki: https://www.google.com/search?&q=git+apply+unrecognized+input has its first hit on a StackOverflow post about colorized diffs. That seems like the most likely problem.

Comment: So how do I continue after making `git revert --no-commit` ? Nothing happens when I do `git revert --continue`.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś: After `git revert --no-commit`, you just keep working as usual: edit files if you like, `git add` if/when you like, `git rm` if/when you like, and finally, `git commit`.